# Top positioned horizontal scroll with css, scrollbar not visible with transform

Tags: css, safari

I have an element on the page with horizontally scrolled content, scrollbar across the top.

This is working in FF/Chrome, and partially working in Safari.

The issue in Safari is the scroll bar is present & functional, but not visible. In the jsfiddle in Safari you can click and scroll across the top, even though no scrollbar shows.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwilson/pm2a9xnd/19/)

```
.testOne {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scrollbar-color: #ffde00 #f7f7f7;
}

.testOne::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 20px;
}

.testOne::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ffde00;
}

.testTwo {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    visibility: visible;
}

.item {
  padding-right: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

<ul class="testContainer">
  <span class="testOne">
    <span class="testTwo">
      <li class="item">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/255x255/f0f0f0/000000' alt='' title=''/>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/255x255/f0f0f0/000000' alt='' title=''/>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/255x255/f0f0f0/000000' alt='' title=''/>
      </li>
    </span>
  </span>
</ul>
```

Hoping someone has run into this and can advise a way to show the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have transforms on direct child elements it's having the issue. Try moving the transform up one level to the `.testContainer` element.

```css
.testContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.testOne {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.testOne::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 20px;
}

.testOne::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #ffde00;
}

.testTwo {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
}

.item {
  padding-right: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="testContainer">
  <span class="testOne">
    <span class="testTwo">
      <li class="item">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/255x255/f0f0f0/000000' alt='' title=''/>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/255x255/f0f0f0/000000' alt='' title=''/>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <img src='http://dummyimage.com/255x255/f0f0f0/000000' alt='' title=''/>
      </li>
    </span>
  </span>
</ul>
```